Merging two tuples according to a given criteria
Suppose that we have two tuples a and b.
I want to implement a function merge_tuples that creates a new tuple c that is a merge of a and b according to a provided binary mask: if a bit is set, we take one item of a, otherwise we take one item of b.
Note that the returned tuple should reference the items of a and b (i.e. we don't want to copy objects here).
Example:
#include <tuple>
#include <cassert>

template<unsigned long long MASK, typename...A, typename...B>
auto merge_tuples (std::tuple<A...>& a, std::tuple<B...>& b)
{
    // In the example below, we kwow that we have to return the following:
    return std::tie
    (
        std::get<0> (a),
        std::get<0> (b),
        std::get<1> (a),
        std::get<1> (b),
        std::get<2> (b)
    );
    
    // BUT HOW TO DO IT GENERICALLY BY USING 'MASK' ?
}

int main ()
{
    std::tuple<float,int>        a {float {3.1},   int{2}          };
    std::tuple<double,int,char>  b {double{1.123}, int{4}, char{9} };

    auto c = merge_tuples <0b00101> (a,b);
    
    assert (std::get<0>(c) == float {3.1}  );   // mask[0]==1  => take item 0 from a
    assert (std::get<1>(c) == double{1.123});   // mask[1]==0  => take item 0 from b
    assert (std::get<2>(c) == int   {2}    );   // mask[2]==1  => take item 1 from a
    assert (std::get<3>(c) == int   {4}    );   // mask[3]==0  => take item 1 from b
    assert (std::get<4>(c) == char  {9}    );   // mask[4]==0  => take item 2 from b
}

How can such a merge_tuples function be implemented?

One can implement it, but nobody is going to do it for you.

@ALX23z: fair enough, it is already an answer to know that can be done and that this is no dead end. I'm currently trying to find a way to do it but my meta-programming skills are not that good. Still trying though !

The tricky parts is going to be that the mask type is 64 bits long but you only actually want to use 5 bits.  I would suggest rethinking how you pass in the sequence and instead take reformat the function to template<int... Mask, typename...A, typename...B> auto merge_tuples (std::tuple<A...>& a, std::tuple<B...>& b)  That would turn the call into auto c = merge_tuples <0,0,1,0,1> (a,b);.  That should make the function easier to implement as well.

@NathanOliver: following your idea, it would be possible to concatenate the two tuples first and then provide an integer list that provides the required indexes instead, (0,2,1,3,4) in the example. I guess that generating this list is not too hard. However, one needs then a tuple_cat that returns references on the items of a and b

@ALX23z I guess you were wrong about that :P

std::index_sequence might help:
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>, N>
mask_to_array(std::uint64_t mask)
{
    std::array<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>, N> res{};
    std::size_t ai = 0;
    std::size_t bi = 0;

    for (auto& [ab, i] : res) {
        ab = mask & 1;
        i = ab ? ai++ : bi++;
        mask >>= 1; 
    }
    return res;
}

template <std::uint64_t MASK, typename...A, typename...B>
constexpr auto merge_tuples (std::tuple<A...>& a, std::tuple<B...>& b)
{
    constexpr std::size_t N = sizeof...(A) + sizeof...(B);
    constexpr auto arr = mask_to_array<N>(MASK);

    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::tie(std::get<arr[Is].second>(std::get<arr[Is].first>(std::tie(b, a)))...);

    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

Demo

A way to do that would be something like
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<bool... Bs>
using bool_sequence = std::integer_sequence<bool, Bs...>;

// Compile time check if bit at pos Idx is set in Mask
template<std::size_t Idx, long long Mask>
constexpr bool
is_bit_set()
{
    return static_cast<bool>((Mask >> Idx) & 1);
}

// Extract a sequence of bools from mask to tell whether
// each bit is set
template<long long Mask, std::size_t... Is>
auto decompose(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return bool_sequence<is_bit_set<Is, Mask>()...>{};
}

// Recursion to build a list of indices to access in
// the tuples based on the mask
template<std::size_t IA = 0, std::size_t IB = 0, bool FirstB, bool... Bs, std::size_t... Is>
auto make_indices_impl(bool_sequence<FirstB, Bs...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    if constexpr (FirstB) {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Bs) == 0) {
            return std::index_sequence<Is..., IA>{ };
        } else {
            return make_indices_impl<IA + 1, IB>(bool_sequence<Bs...>{}, std::index_sequence<Is..., IA>{});
        }
    } else {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Bs) == 0) {
            return std::index_sequence<Is..., IB>{ };
        } else {
            return make_indices_impl<IA, IB + 1>(bool_sequence<Bs...>{}, std::index_sequence<Is..., IB>{});
        }
    }
}

// For easier invocation
template<bool... Bs>
auto make_indices(bool_sequence<Bs...> b)
{
    return make_indices_impl(b, std::index_sequence<>{});
}

// Extract a single member of a tuple based on a selection
// toggle and index
template<bool Sel, std::size_t Idx, class TupA, class TupB>
decltype(auto) extract_tup_mem(TupA&& a, TupB&& b)
{
    if constexpr (Sel)
        return std::get<Idx>(a);
    else
        return std::get<Idx>(b);
}

// Fold expression to build a tuple with the correct members
template<class TupA, class TupB, bool... Bs, std::size_t... Is>
auto
merge_tups_impl(TupA&& a, TupB&& b, bool_sequence<Bs...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::tie(extract_tup_mem<Bs, Is>(std::forward<TupA>(a), std::forward<TupB>(b))...);
}

// Cobmbine all the bits and pieces to merge the tuples
template<long long Mask, class TupA, class TupB>
auto
merge_tups(TupA&& a, TupB&& b)
{
    constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<TupA>>::value + std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<TupB>>::value;
    auto bool_seq = decompose<Mask>(std::make_index_sequence<size>());
    auto idx_seq = make_indices(bool_seq);
    return merge_tups_impl(std::forward<TupA>(a), std::forward<TupB>(b), bool_seq, idx_seq);
}

Check the implementation by executing this code
template<class... Args, std::size_t... Is>
void print_impl(std::tuple<Args...>& a, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    ((std::cout << std::get<Is>(a) << " "), ...);
}

template<class... Args>
void print(std::tuple<Args...>& t)
{
    print_impl(t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>());
}

int main()
{
    std::tuple a = {1, false, "hello" };
    std::tuple b = {nullptr, 3.5f };

    auto merged = merge_tups<0b01011>(a, b);
    print(merged);
}


This is a partial answer to my question. Instead of providing a mask, one provides the indexes of the items in the target tuple. Then, one has just to concatenate a and b by using std::tie to get references.
#include <tuple>
#include <cassert>

template<int...IDX, typename...A, typename...B>
auto merge_tuples (std::tuple<A...>& a, std::tuple<B...>& b)
{
    auto aa = std::apply ([] (auto&&... args) { return std::tie(args...); }, a);
    auto bb = std::apply ([] (auto&&... args) { return std::tie(args...); }, b);

    auto c = std::tuple_cat(aa,bb);

    return std::tie (std::get<IDX>(c)...);
}

int main ()
{
    std::tuple<float,int>        a {float {3.1},   int{2}          };
    std::tuple<double,int,char>  b {double{1.123}, int{4}, char{9} };

    auto c = merge_tuples <0,2,1,3,4> (a,b);

    assert (std::get<0>(c) == float {3.1}  );   // item 0 from a
    assert (std::get<1>(c) == double{1.123});   // item 0 from b
    assert (std::get<2>(c) == int   {2}    );   // item 1 from a
    assert (std::get<3>(c) == int   {4}    );   // item 1 from b
    assert (std::get<4>(c) == char  {9}    );   // item 2 from b
}


